# sklearn LDA unique labels issue

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a code that I used to run which uses LDA (linear discriminant analysis) class from sklearn.lda module. Now it is gives the error below. Lately I updated the sklearn package, I think it might be caused by that. However, I still could not understand what the problem is. Could you tell me what is wrong with putting 1 and -1 as labels? As far as I understand problem is related to my labeling.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-94-9935ca0189ad>", line 1, in <module>
    lda.fit([atom.coords for atom in nm_1.atoms], nm_1.correlations[1][0])

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\lda.py", line 415, in fit
    self.classes_ = unique_labels(y)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 106, in unique_labels
    raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % ys)

ValueError: Unknown label type: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1.,
       -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
       -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
       -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
       -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
       -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
       -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
       -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
       -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
       -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
       -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
       -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
       -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
       -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
       -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
       -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
       -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.])
```

Comment: Did you pass an array of arrays or a list of arrays as y?

Comment: Yes it is an array, I think I solved the problem. I think it might have a problem with float type. I turned it into an integer array and now it seems to be running fine. I wrote `lda.fit(atom_coords, correlations.astype(int))` and i did not get errors anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the 1/-1 labeling, as sklearn.lda works well with even string labels:

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>from sklearn.lda import LDA
>>>X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
>>>y = np.array([1, 1, 1, "y","y","y"])
>>>clf = LDA()
>>>clf.fit(X, y)
>>>(clf.predict([[-0.8, -1],[3,2]]))
['1' 'y']
```

You probably have a problem with the labels object itself - are you sure it is an array?

Comment: @zamk if you found the problem please update\answer your own post